# How to categorize the list of names based on their first letter in PySpark in Colab notebook?

Tags: python, pyspark, google-colaboratory

I want to categorize the list of names based on their first character using the groupby and map commands. This list contains a number of names. How should I do it? Can anyone help me? I write code in a Colab notebook with pysperk. I am a beginner and don't know how to do it.

```
arrayStructureData = [
    ("Sajad","M"),
    ("Hassan","F"),
    ("Ali","F"),
    ("Hossein","M")]
arrayStructureSchema = StructType([
     StructField('Name', StringType(), True),
     StructField('gender', StringType(), True)
     ])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = arrayStructureData, schema = arrayStructureSchema)
```

Comment: Please share your expected result given the provided df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `substring` then `groupby`?

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .withColumn('c', F.substring('Name', 0, 1))
    .groupBy('c')
    .agg(
        F.count('*').alias('cnt')
    )
    .show()
)

+---+---+
|  c|cnt|
+---+---+
|  A|  1|
|  S|  1|
|  H|  2|
+---+---+
```